# Injecting $attrs in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have some JavaScript written in the context of AngularJS. My relevant JavaScript looks like the following:

```
.factory('$myFactory', function ($myLibrary, $interpolate) {
 return {
   myFunction: function ($scope, $attrs, p) {
     if (p !== null) {
       $attrs.set('myProperty', p);
     }
   }
 };
```

I am trying to unit test this code. In an attempt to unit test the code, I'm using Jasmine.

```
it('should set myProperty', inject(function ($scope, $myFactory) {
//  $myFactory.myFunction($scope
}));
```

I can't figure out how to inject some $attrs from my unit test. How do I do that? I can successfully get my $scope setup. However, I don't understand how to inject $attrs. Is there something special about it that I'm not aware of? I'm having a similar issue with $element, though that one is out of the context of this specific test.

Thank you!

Comment: Why Are you injecting `$scope` and `$attrs` into a service from the first place?

Comment: working with an inherited code base :/

Comment: ouch! Why are you testing a bad code anyway? I would invest my time to refactor it first. $scope and $attrs should only live inside directives/controllers

Comment: Can you please show me the code which use this factory?

Comment: It's used in a LOT of different places. Is there something specific you're looking for? Because its used in so many places is one of the reasons I need to unit test this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k1cxSjpAXhhJUEOcx9PG

Maybe there is a better solution but That's what I got.

- `$scope` is easy to get, you can inject `$rootScope` everywhere
- `$attrs` on the other hand is only available through the `$compile` variable (it lives in [**compile.js**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.9/src/ng/compile.js))

My solution is to create a **fake controller** , to **compile** it and to hijack it's `$attrs`.

#### So that's how it looks like:

```
var injected = null

function fakeController($scope, $attrs, $element){
  injected = {}
  injected.$scope = $scope;
  injected.$attrs = $attrs;
  injected.$element = $element;
}

describe('Testing a Hello World controller', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var $attrs = null;
  var $element = null;

  var ctrl = null;

  //you need to indicate your module in a test
  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $controller) {

    $compile('<span ng-controller="fakeController"></span>')($rootScope);

    $scope = injected.$scope;
    $attrs = injected.$attrs;
    $element = injected.$element;

    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      $attrs: $attrs,
      $element: $element
    });

  }));

  it('should say hallo to the World', function() {
    expect($scope.name).toEqual('World');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I do not believe it works correctly. For instance, if I'm trying to test 'MainCtrl' in your sample, it fails as soon as I add $attrs as a parameter on 'MainCtrl'. I've updated the Plunkr you listed to demonstrate what I'm referring to.

Comment: You must probably not injecting the right scope, check my update answer / plunker

Comment: I'd upvote more if I could.  I used this to test the concepts outlined in this article: http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/11/lets-make-full-ass-angularjs-directives/

Comment: Great - always love to see how certain features can be hijacked. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

seems that you can just instantiate the controller with empty object, as well...

```
ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
  $scope: $scope,
  $attrs: {}
});
```

Comment: also passing attributes properties you wan to test i.e. `$attrs: {'myProperty', 'some value'}`

Answer (score 2):

In latest versions of AngularJS a controller needs to be provided to get full $attrs.

See [$controllerProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider) documentation.

#### Here's a snippet

```
describe('angular-component-controller', function() {

  // save injected parameters of controller
  var injected = {};
  var controller;

  // @see $https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$componentController
  // we need to extract those from $compile instead of use as locals
  angular.module('locals', []).controller('controller',
    ['$attrs', function($attrs) {
      injected.$attrs = $attrs;
    }]
  );

  beforeEach(module('locals'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $componentController) {
    // invoke dummy component to get $attrs
    $compile('<span ng-controller="controller">')($rootScope);

    var locals = {};
    locals.$scope = $rootScope.$new();
    locals.$attrs = injected.$attrs;

    var bindings = {};

    controller = $componentController('component', locals, bindings);
  }));    
});
```

See this gist [AngularJS $componentController unit test](https://gist.github.com/rjmveloso/1a3cd23a36e5ab61cb85e1e3bf0531d4)